# Using Parse.com for iOS SDK after retired, crash?

Tags: parse-platform

My app switch to Firebase, but part of the enterprise users quickly can not be updated.
If my app continue to use the Parse.com iOS SDK after Parse.com retired, do my app will come to crash?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depend on your code but usually it will not crash what will happened is that your app will try to execute requests to parse.com and because parse.com will not be available you will receive **timeout error** after ~30 seconds but it will not make your iOS SDK code to crash.